# How to assign values to a data table from a second table if both first row and and column values match

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data.tables similar to tables below. I want to find the values from the first table if the values of first column and column names between two tables match and assign it to the second table.

I tried to generate similar examples using mtcars dataset

```
mtcars_first <- add_column(mtcars, car = rownames(mtcars), .before =  1)


mtcars_second <- rbind(
                   c("Hornet 4 Drive",NA,NA,NA),
                   c("Valiant",NA,NA,NA),
                   c("Duster 360" ,NA,NA,NA)) %>% as.data.table()
```

colnames(mtcars_second) <- c("car","disp","drat","qsec")

Comment: This would be a whole lot easier if you didn't encode the column names both as column names and as a row of values. In addition to looking weird, it also prevents you from having numeric values in the table. Is this by design? Is there a reason you need to _start_ with stringified data such as this? If you need the column names repeated in the first row in a report, perhaps that step can be done at the very end of your processing.

Comment: (Not to mention that since your `mtcars_second` has column names `V1` through `V4`, there has to be manual matching to try to get things to work.)

Comment: @r2evans I updated the question according to your comments. I still have problem to do matching on both col names and one of the column

Answer (score 0):

```r
mtcars_second[mtcars_first, c("disp","drat","qsec") := .(i.disp, i.drat, i.qsec), on=.(car)]
mtcars_second
#               car   disp   drat   qsec
#            <char> <char> <char> <char>
# 1: Hornet 4 Drive    258   3.08  19.44
# 2:        Valiant    225   2.76  20.22
# 3:     Duster 360    360   3.21  15.84
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great. I wonder how to pass the parameters name to column names used here inside a function. Say y1,y2,y3 are the variable names in function equivalent to ("disp","drat","qsec") and y4 is equivalent to car. thanks I am still new data.table

Comment: more name-agnostic: `as.data.table(mtcars_first[, names(mtcars_second)])[mtcars_second[,.(car)], on = .(car)]`

Comment: (though that's an inner join that may miss something in `second` that is not in `first`)